# Instantiate View controller with its tab bar from unlinked viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewController related to a Tab Bar Controller: the first one.

Clicking on a cell of its tableview, I'll show programmatically another viewController that's not linked to the first viewController with no segue (because of right reasons).

Now, my goal is to present/instantiate the second viewController related to the tab bar mentioned at the beginning of this question.

If I'll use this:

`let vc=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "offerteView") as! SecondViewController`

It'll be presented the mentioned viewController without the tab bar of course.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embed the first view controller in a **navigation controller** and use its `pushViewController` function to show the second view controller.

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "offerteView") as! SecondViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: The first viewcontroller has already a navigation controller: it's the tabbar.

The problem, is that the second one has no navigation contorller: I would like to present it.

Comment: @LorenzoN. The tab bar controller is **not** a navigation controller.

Comment: Ok, sorry: I didn't know it. 
Well I don't know how to do it: the first one should have the tabbar too. How can I?

Comment: If you are using Interface Builder, link the "view controllers" relationship to the navigation controller, and the navigation controller"s "root view controller" relationship to the first VC.

Comment: Please, can you link me a complete example about it?

Answer (score 0):

when using tab bars the view controllers are called on the basis of their Index and because of this the tab bars are still maintained and this can be done like this.

```
self.tabBarController!.selectedViewController! = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers[3]
```

where [3] is the index position of the View Controller.

or

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

//Hope it was helpful. Happy Coding.